# Need Expanded EXCEL Date/Time table to include week number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Date/Time table and now need to incorporate the week number in the month (starting on Mondays) to meet certain criteria for a look up algorithm.

Google searching online I've come across this:

```
= WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR($A2),1,DAY($A2-WEEKDAY($A2,3))))
```

The problem is that my Table starts on 1/1/2010 and when it gets to the first Monday of the month (Jan 4th) the week number rolls to 2 instead of 1

[image: Improper roll]

It resolves itself when Feb hits

[image]

but then hits it again (and again and again) in April

[image]

Now if I edit the formula to ISOWEEKNUM

```
= ISOWEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A33),1,DAY(A33-WEEKDAY(A33,3))))
```

it gets even more wacked

[image]

How to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just divide the DAY return by 7.  Return the INT() and add 1:

```
=INT((DAY($A2-WEEKDAY($A2,3)))/7)+1
```

[image]

Comment: That works but I must admit I'm struggling to understand how/why

DAY($A2-WEEKDAY($A2,3)) = DAY(1/1/2010-4) = 28?

Comment: and then 28/7 = 4 then we add 1.  The day formula will always return the day number of the monday prior.  We just need to find which monday it is.  If it is less then 7 the int will return 0 because 6/7 is `0.somthing` and we want it to  be 1.

Comment: Ahhh thank you! it was the day return that I wasn't grasping, got the Int() /7+1 return. Thanks again!!!